# Ionic Angular App. I cannot get width of div using @ViewChild nativeElement. Why?

Tags: ionic4, angular8

I am trying to get the width of a div that wraps a canvas so I can resize the canvas to match the width and paint the canvas as appropriate for that width.
As seen in the console log, the width of the div is returning ZERO.
What am I missing?

My versions are "@angular/core": "~8.1.2" and "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",

AMENDMENT TO QUESTION: 09/03/2019

*I find that if I move the code that inspects the div width to the ngAfterViewChecked() lifecycle event it works ... sort of. Inside ngAfterViewChecked I manipulate the canvas content and find that the manipulation causes ngAfterViewChecked to run again. And on the third iteration it finds the correct width and completes its work. I would like to understand the underlying reason and a better solution.*

My console log shows:

```
ScanLinkComponent ngAfterViewInit
canvas 100
div 0
```

My HTML

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title color="primary">
            Test
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>

            <div #wrapperDiv
                 id="wrapperDiv"
                 width="100%">

                <canvas #canvasElement
                        id="canvasElement"
                        width="100"
                        height="150">

                </canvas>

            </div>

        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

My TypeScript

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component( {
    selector: 'app-scan-link',
    templateUrl: './scan-link.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './scan-link.component.scss' ],
} )
export class ScanLinkComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild(
        'wrapperDiv',
        { static: false }
    )
    public divView: ElementRef;

    @ViewChild(
        'canvasElement',
        { static: false }
    )
    public canvasView: ElementRef;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {

        console.log( 'ScanLinkComponent ngAfterViewInit' );

        console.log( 'canvas ' + this.canvasView.nativeElement.width );

        console.log( 'div ' + this.divView.nativeElement.clientWidth );

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting it yourself [using Chrome tools](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/android#using-chrome-devtools), to check that isn't the real width? If the canvas has some kind of float or absolute positioning, then that could be the real width of the div as it doesn't see anything inside of it.

Comment: Btw it looks like you have got lucky with this one, but `.width` seems that it [isn't always a number](https://javascript.info/task/width-vs-clientwidth) - (click view solution).